# What are some examples of Machine Translation applications/libraries currently being developed?

Tags: open-source, nlp, machine-translation

I'm interested in learning more about Machine Translation.  While I have some very interesting books on the matter, I'd like to see some real world applications of MT's theories.

I've found a couple open source projects just by searching around:

[Apertium](http://www.apertium.org/)

[Moses](http://www.statmt.org/moses/)

So, does anyone have any other examples?  I'm looking for active projects; stuff which has not been abandoned.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Machine Translation Packages**

Besides [Moses](http://www.statmt.org/moses/) and [Apertium](http://www.apertium.org/), other good open source tools for machine translation that are being actively developed/supported are:

- [cdec (C++)](http://cdec-decoder.org/index.php?title=Main_Page)
- [Joshua (Java)](http://sourceforge.net/projects/joshua/)
- [Jane (C++)](http://www-i6.informatik.rwth-aachen.de/jane/)
- [Phrasal (Java) - soon to be released](http://nlp.stanford.edu/phrasal/)

Answer (score 0):

Apertium 3.0.1 is an very good tool for machine translation scheme . i have worked on it. it is avail for most common languages. very simplest appilication for translation . it can be run through shell or bash scripts